# Phone number formatting in Salesforce

Tags: formatting, salesforce

If I enter a phone number as `(238)654-2332` into a phone field, it should be displayed in `0123456789` format and automatically remove the braces, unneeded spaces and special characters.

You can see on the below screenshot that there is a phone number with braces, but my requirement is to automatically remove braces and display the phone in `0123456789` format: [image: screenshot]

Could you please advise me on the best approach for my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration options would be Workflow, Flow or Process Builder (check help resources or maybe some self-paced training at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home)

Workflows don't do regular expressions for search-replace but they do have a [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) function so maybe something like this would be a good start: `SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Phone, '(', ''), ')', ''), '-', '')`.

Or with a bit of code (Apex trigger that'd run "before insert, before update") you could fairly easily strip all non-digit characters. Again - if you've never written SF code before you might have to attack some training first.

```
String x = '(238)654-2332';
String cleaned = x.replaceAll('[^0-9]', '');
System.debug(cleaned); // 2386542332
```